# one SVG is not displayed, other works - maybe the port is not working?

Tags: html, svg

i want to display a SVG with links in my browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome) using it as object. (Or any other method)

Well, a SVG on another server works, the SVG on my server does not work.
Do you have any idea why?
My only idea is, that the port is part of the problem and the object is not allowed to include port information.

I tried several combinations. I believe the following tries are the most relevant ones (which one works is commented in the same line):

```html
<img src="http://MYSERVER:3000/SEVERALPATHES/IMAGE.svg" /> Image is displayed but the links do not work
<object data="http://MYSERVER:3000/SEVERALPATHES/IMAGE.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> Does not work at all
<object data="http://svg.tutorial.aptico.de/grafik_svg/kap5_1.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> works completely
```

Does anyone have an idea what I can change to display this SVG with full functionality in my HTML-Code.
The data requires an URL. Are ports allowed there?

Comment: SVG when displayed as an image is not interactive so links don't work by design. What does does not work at all mean?

Comment: yes, I know, that <img> is not interactive, it was just to show, that the URL works.

does not work at all = Nothing is shown.

Comment: Does the SVG have height and width defined on the root svg element.

Comment: Yes, it does
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width='300px' height='300px'>

Comment: @kaiido probably just SO comment formatting.

Comment: I gave it some further tries ...
It does not seem to be the port, so I'll check what the server is doing ...

Comment: Make sure your server "MYSERVER" is setting the correct ContentType for the SVG files. It needs to be "image/svg+xml" or the image will not display. Also make sure IMAGE.svg is a valid standalone SVG. Standalone (external) SVG files must have an `xmlns` declaration in the root `<svg>` element.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a "direct" solution, but I was able to embed the SVG directly to the HTML.
Nice side effect: Only one HTML-Connection :-)